# Transaction performance and how to lighten transaction manager?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm working about a identity, access and role management with SDN 2.1.0-RC4 without AspectJ.
This system aims to manage around 120 000 users and data is extracted from legacy and HR applications.
I have from 500 to 30000 updates/day, so performance can be a touchy subject
I ran some workbenches with default configuration.

I used a very simple and stupid way.
A simple class

```
@TypeAlias("event")
@NodeEntity
public class Event {

    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;

    @Indexed
    private Long eventId;

    @RelatedTo(type="PREVIOUS_EVENT", direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Event previous;

    private String description;

        /.../
}
```

and I insert data one by one

```
    /.../
/**
 * 
 */
public void loadAllData() {

    Event root = new Event();
    root.setEventId(0L);
    root.setDescription("ROOT");

    repository.save(root);
    Event curr = root;


    for(int i = 0; i< SIZE; i ++) {
        curr = insertData(curr, i );
    }
}


/**
 * @param curr
 * @param i
 * @return
 */
public Event insertData(Event curr, int i) {
    long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Event evt = new Event();
    evt.setEventId(curr.getEventId()+1);
    evt.setPrevious(curr);
    evt.setDescription("event #"+i);
    repository.save(evt);
    curr = evt;
    delais[i] = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime;
    return curr;

}
/.../
```

I test several by overloading theses methods

1) use of @Transactional

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Event insertData(Event curr, int i) {
    return super.insertData(curr, i);
}
```

2) Use of neo4j transaction

```
@Override
public void loadAllData() {
    gds = getContext().getBean(GraphDatabaseService.class);
    super.loadAllData();
}       

@Override
public Event insertData(Event curr, int i) {                
    Transaction tx = gds.beginTx();
    try {
        curr = super.insertData(curr, i);
        tx.success();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        tx.failure();
    } finally {
        tx.finish();
    }
    return curr;

}
```

I know benchmark are a trolling subject and it's not what I want. So take theses values as they are: a stupid test

Results

**JtaTransactionManager**

Mean 47,20 ms, Min 21,00 ms, Max 425,00 ms

**GraphDatabaseService**

Mean 0,90 ms, Min 0,00 ms, Max 3,00 ms

JtaTransactionManager is very slow compared to native neo4j server, but JtaTransactionManager is a global and ambitious TransactionManager.

My purpose is how to lighten or create a custom transactionManager with less ambition, a smaller scope but still using the @Transactional annotation ?

May be I've missed something ?

Thanks you for any potential help or advice.

PS: my configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="benchmark"/>

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="benchmark.repository"/>
    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>


    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase" 
      destroy-method="shutdown">
         <constructor-arg index="0" value="data/benchmark.db" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Marc DeXeT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use two totally differen transaction batch sizes.

With the "neo4j" TM you use a global tx scope that includes all your updates in one go (aka several hundred or thousand ops).

With the `@Transactional` you have a tx scope of a single operation. So the overhead of the transaction is added for each operation instead just once.

So try to put an @Transactional around the `loadAllData()` instead.

Also for a higher insertion speed try to use `template.createRelationshipBetween(...., duplicate=true)` instead of `evt.setPrevious(curr)`. So you skip all the delta detection and duplication elimination.

Comment: Thanks. @Transactionnal is a cascading feature, isn't it ? Deep method call transactions are wrapped by first level method transaction I presume. So 'public void run() { upper() //... commit is done } @ Transactional public void upper() { lower(); //... commit is not done } @ Transactional public void lower() { //.. do something ..// // it's not yet committed }